# How to Convert a MongoDB Document to an Object/Class in Tests NodeJS/TypeScript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing

The question I have is on 2 levels.

1. How do I properly cast a `findOne` from MongoDB into a real object?
   (example of problem following)
2. If I can't really do that (from preliminary googling), what's the
   proper way to verify the contents of my MongoDB database after
   running some function (like `insertOne`)?

I'm using just the raw MongoDB driver, no Mongoose. This is a NodeJS app with TypeScript and Mocha for testing.

Let's say I have this example class:

```
export class Person {

    get Name(): string{
        return this.name;
    }
    set Name(value: string) {
        this.name= value;
    }

    constructor(private name: String) {
    }
}
```

Then for some test, I insert a `Person` into the MongoDB database using `insertOne`

```
db.collection.insertOne(new Person("Thomas"));
```

Now, I want to verify that the person was inserted correctly, so I use `findOne` and verify the features.

```
const person: Person = await db.collection.findOne(collection, {-insert Person query-}) as Person;
// Here is what I want to fix (this errors out):
expect(person.Name).to.equal("Thomas");
```

Here, the person is returned as a json object (which is expected). This means the `.Name` property doesn't exist, only `.name`.

Again, the question is at the top of the post! Thank you!